# Why is an expression like ['a']['b'] an error instead of getting values from a nested dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get the subscriber count from a youtube channel using the youtube api. However the repsonse sends a nested dict with more information than just the subscriber count. Here is the code I tried using to solve the problem

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = 'my_key'

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

request = youtube.channels().list(
    part='statistics',
    forUsername='pewdiepie'
    )

response = dict(request.execute())

print(response)
print(['items']['statistics'])
```

However I come up with this error

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is the response I get from the youtube api

```
{'kind': 'youtube#channelListResponse', 'etag': 'b1tpsekLNgax8TyB0hih1FujSL4', 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 1, 'resultsPerPage': 5}, 'items': [{'kind': 'youtube#channel', 'etag': 'gdAP8rVq0n-1Bj2eyjvac-CrtdQ', 'id': 'UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw', 'statistics': {'viewCount': '28147953019', 'subscriberCount': '111000000', 'hiddenSubscriberCount': False, 'videoCount': '4459'}}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response you are posting here, if you want to know statistics from an item, you have to specify from which item you are trying to get statistics. *items* is a list, which means that you have to refer to it's elements by numerical index. It has a length as well, you can get by using *len(response['items'])*. Now, let's say you want to get the *subscriberCount* from the first item in the list, in that case you can retrieve it with the following code:

```
if (len(response['items']) > 0):
    response['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount']
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line in your code to:

```
for item in response['items']:
  print(item['statistics'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a value in a dictionary you actually have to **include the dictionary** in the expression.

`['items']['statistics']` alone creates a list containing one string, `'items'`, and tries to access that list using the string `'statistics'` as index. But this is bad, because list indices must be integers.

In order to access the key `'items'` in the dictionary `response`, you can use `response['items']`.

Assuming this returns another, nested, dictionary, you can then access the key `'statistics'` in that dictionary by using `response['items']['statistics']`.